# Pandas group by two fields, pick min date and next max date from other group

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({'model_id': [1,1,2],
                     'brand': ['nike','nike','nike'],
                     'release_date': ['01/01/2021','01/02/2021','01/03/2021']})
data['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['release_date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Looks like:

```
'|    |   model_id | brand   | release_date        |
 |---:|-----------:|:--------|:--------------------|
 |  0 |          1 | nike    | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
 |  1 |          1 | nike    | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |
 |  2 |          2 | nike    | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |'
```

I want to group by model_id and brand, to get the max and min date, but the max_date of an id must be the min date_from the the next model of the same brand, and NaN if there is none( case for model_id 2).

The expected output is:

```
"|             |        min_date     |        max_date      |
 |:------------|--------------------:|---------------------:|
 | (1, 'nike') | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00  |
 | (2, 'nike') | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |        NaN           |"
```

I have tried running this but I am unable to do the step of picking the next date of the same brand.

```
(data.groupby(['model_id','brand'])
     .agg(min_date=('release_date', np.min), max_date=('release_date', np.max))
     .to_markdown()
 )
```

Note: with the dataframe in a different order the results should not vary

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'model_id':[2,1,2],'brand':['nike','nike','nike'],'release_date':['01/03/2021','01/02/2021','01/01/2021']})

(data
.groupby(['model_id','brand'])
.agg(min_date=('release_date', 'min'))
.assign(max_date=lambda d: d.groupby('brand') 
['min_date'].shift(-1))
)
```

Yields a min_date bigger than max_date

```
"|             | min_date   | max_date   |
 |:------------|:-----------|:-----------|
 | (1, 'nike') | 01/02/2021 | 01/01/2021 |
 | (2, 'nike') | 01/01/2021 | nan        |"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### shifting max_date per group

Here max_date is defined as the min_date of the previous id per brand

```
(data
 .groupby(['model_id','brand'])
 .agg(min_date=('release_date', 'min'))
 .assign(max_date=lambda d: d.groupby('brand')['min_date'].shift(-1))
 #.astype(str).to_markdown() # uncomment for markdown
)
```

output:

```
|             | min_date   | max_date   |
|:------------|:-----------|:-----------|
| (1, 'nike') | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-03 |
| (2, 'nike') | 2021-01-03 | NaT        |
```

###### previous answer

You need to mask the data afterwards:

```
(data
 .groupby(['model_id','brand'])
 .agg(min_date=('release_date', 'min'), max_date=('release_date', 'max'))
 .assign(max_date=lambda d: d['max_date'].mask(d['max_date'].eq(d['min_date'])))
 #.astype(str).to_markdown() # uncomment for markdown
)
```

output (as markdown):

```
|             | min_date   | max_date   |
|:------------|:-----------|:-----------|
| (1, 'nike') | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 |
| (2, 'nike') | 2021-01-03 | NaT        |
```

Comment: Thats great @mozway but if you look at max_date for 1,nike its the very next  value existing for the same brand, so it should be 2021-01-03,  like in the example

Comment: @Pepe then you might want to use a shift per group, check the update

Comment: There seems to be an issue, does it matter if the data is ordererd? I am getting in the bigger dataframe some cases where min_date > max_date (should never be the case)

Comment: Yes it matters, although `groupby` should perform a sorting of the groups. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example that fails?

Comment: just did it, seems like simply changing the order of the df trigers a min_date > max_date in some cases, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: upon further inspection in the second chained groupby the data with month '3'  which should be the value picked is not there when printing the groups, you can see it 
 .assign(max_date=lambda d: print(d)))

Comment: I did not understand your comment

Comment: Sorry, if you see the edit, when the model_id 1 has a unique entry with the date between model_id 2 it picks the wrong value, making so min_date > max_date, I added the code to reproduce it but I am not sure how to handle it

Comment: I think there is an issue of logic here. You wanted to get the value of the next group, so this is independent of the max_date of the current group

Comment: Okay will not annoy anymore, can you give me any hint then? I needed the the constraint that min_date is always smaller than max_date. It's taking the min_date for every record and the min of the next group

Comment: It's not that I don't want to give you a hint, it is just that I am now not sure I fully grasp what you want to do. Maybe you should ask a follow up question with a slightly more complex example?

Comment: Tried to expain here better, thank you a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71767260/pandas-group-and-pick-the-min-and-the-min-of-the-next-group